# Nodemailer, when I get an email the from is incorrect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer

I thought this was working fine until I realized when I get the message in gmail the sender(from) is me `myemail@gmail.com`? It should be coming from `req.body.email` right?

```
router.post('/send_message', function(req,res) {

  // create reusable transporter object using SMTP transport 
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
      pass: 'pass'
    }
  });

  transporter.sendMail({
      from: req.body.email,
      to: 'myemail@gmail.com',
      subject: req.body.subject,
      text: req.body.message
  }, function(err, info) {

    res.send('Emailed successfully');

  });

});
```

Comment: you're logging into gmail as you and thus sending as you, what's the problem? if you want a "vanity from", use your own email server instead of logging into gmail.

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding the configuration then, thats the problem, in order for someone to send me an email on the contact form they would have to get authenticated by google?

Comment: Maybe thats fine though, it's just a website contact form, maybe I just add the users email address inside the message or something. So that way I dont have to do any auth. I guess I didnt really think for the sender to be valid they would actually need to be authenticated.

Comment: I guess my question is what is the purpose of `transporter.sendMail` from option then?

Comment: if i had to guess (and thats all i'm doing), i would suspect that _from_ is more of a pop/smtp thing, and that the gmail feature doesn't use it. that said, just put their email somewhere else you can control.